# Error when passing reading file command from C# to R by using R.Net

Tags: c#, r

I used R.Net to integrate R to C# program. I have this code:

```
private void drawChart(REngine engine)
    {
        StringBuilder plotCommmand = new StringBuilder();
        plotCommmand.Append("sigmod = read.table(file=\"inproceedings.csv\", header=TRUE, sep=\"~\", quote=\"\", comment=\"\");");            
        Console.WriteLine(plotCommmand.ToString());
        engine.EagerEvaluate(plotCommmand.ToString());            
    }
```

When running the program, I received the exception "Error in the application." at this line:

```
engine.EagerEvaluate(plotCommmand.ToString());
```

Please tell me what is the mistake with my code?

Comment: why downvote me? I really need help =.='

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by replacing this code:

```
plotCommmand.Append("sigmod = read.table(file=\"inproceedings.csv\", header=TRUE, sep=\"~\", quote=\"\", comment=\"\");");
```

by:

```
plotCommmand.Append(@"sigmod <- read.table(file='C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\R\\inproceedings.csv', header=TRUE, sep='~', quote='', comment.char='');");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using EagerEvaluate which is an obsolete method, suggesting you are using an old version of R.NET. The following code works fine for me, using the latest codebase, and I expect it would work equally well with the latest release available via NuGet or at https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/releases

```
StringBuilder plotCommmand = new StringBuilder();
plotCommmand.Append("sigmod = read.table(file='c:/tmp/test.csv', header=TRUE, sep='~', quote='', comment='')");
Console.WriteLine(plotCommmand.ToString());
engine.Evaluate(plotCommmand.ToString());
engine.Evaluate("str(sigmod)");
```

Comment: I tried as you said, but I got another exception: `InvalidOperationException was unhandled` at another line `rEngine.Evaluate(@"library(Cairo);");`